# how to change output.ui to output.py file?

Tags: python

I have designed a GUI by Qt designer, then save the file as output.ui.
I want to apply my functions(written in pyCharm) to the output.ui.

how can I change the output.ui to output.py in pycharm??
thanks

Comment: It's documented at http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html

Comment: You can see how it is done with PyQt here:http://www.technicaljar.com/?p=688 maybe that'll help